# How can I implement 'irwi (wikipedia gem)' to my existing app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, wiki

I added `irwi` ( https://github.com/alno/irwi ) to my app.

I'd like it accessible when user access to http://example.com/shop/:shop_name/wiki
(I need to know how routes.rb should be)

Anyone can show me how to make it?

:shop_name is slug so that it could be various pattern.
Of course each `shop` record should have a wikipedia ( one-to-one here. When shop is being created, one wikipedia page for it should be created automatically at the same time. )

I'm using Cancan, and devise for authentication so if possible, I want it only the registered user can edit and update wikipedia page.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html for how to do your routing if you want more detailed help you will have to provide more code. Will be something along the lines of-

```
resource :wiki, :controller => :shop, :only => [] do
  get :wiki
  post :wiki
end
```

depending on what you require wiki to be able to do, your controllers etc. you should just be able to use the

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

for your authentication